# Calling property as if it is a method

Tags: c#, wpf

I've this property in ViewModel

```
private string _message;
public string Logger
{
        get { return _message; }
        set
        {
            _message = Logger.GetMessage();
            Instance.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
 }
```

This property set automatically the value from an instance of Logger. Now I've a problem, for assign the content to a  Label I should do this:

```
Label.Content = ViewModel.Logger;
```

But I want only call the property like this:

```
ViewModel.Logger;
```

Because the value is set internally to the property automatically, the problem's that I got this message:

> Can be used as instructions only assignments, calls, increases, decreases and new expressions

The label will be update automatically because I've set the binding:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Logger, IsAsync=True}" />
```

Any idea?

Comment: why don't you make a method?

Comment: @thumbmunkeys I want use a property instead

Comment: A property is intended for access, which is reading and writing, not execution with a side effect.

Comment: so I should create another method that get the value from the property and pass it to the label..?

Comment: You can use the property to get, and a method to set. @D3bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `XAML` is right. You can change your `Logger` property as following:

```
private string _message;
    public string Logger
    {
        get 
        {
            if (_message == null)
            {
                _message = Logger.GetMessage();
            }
            return _message; }
        set
        {
            _message = Logger.GetMessage();
            Instance.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

and you don't need to use any

```
Label.Content = ViewModel.Logger;
```

or

```
ViewModel.Logger;
```

cause of `binding` the `get` method will get executed and first time when `_message` field is `null`, your value logic(`GetMessage()`) will get executed and `Lable` will show the value.

Comment: but if I need to update the message calling `Logger.GetMessage()`? I need to recall the property.. Your code is good only if I need to initialize the control

Comment: @D3bug if you only get values from Logger.GetMessage() then you should  keep the set message as you have already defined in your code. No need to change. simple. then doesn't metter what you asssign to your property it will always pick value from Logger.GetMessage(). Is that what you want?

Comment: yes but calling .Content with databinding sound's strange

Comment: @D3bug you don't need to do that, you have raise the change in setter, OnPropertyChanged(), I'm hoping it's the Inotifypropertychanged implementation. so the value will get reflected into Label, No explicit assignment is required. :)

Comment: @D3bug relieved to hear that ;)

Comment: if you could help me with this problem I'll be glad: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37545452/stackoverflowexception-using-viewmodel

Comment: @D3bug yeah! sure.

Answer (score 4):

> But I want only call the property like this:
>
> ```
> ViewModel.Logger;
> ```

You can't. Properties are not methods. If you intend to use a property as a method, create a method instead.

You can't expect a `Label` to set a value either, so your entire binding is pointless. You can use the property to get, and a method to set instead.